# How to force interrupt to restart main loop instead of resuming? (timing issue!)

Tags: loops, arduino, interrupt, isr

For the last two days i wrote a program that in basic terms generates a fairly accurate user adjustable pulse signal (both frequency and duty cycle adjustable). It basically uses the micros() function to keep track of time in order to pull low or high the 4 digital output channels.

These 4 channels need to have a phase difference of 90 degrees (think a 4cyl engine) always. In order for the user to change settings an ISR is implemented which returns a flag to the main loop to re-initialise the program. This flag is defined as a boolean 'set4'. When it is false a 'while' statement in the main loop will run the outputs. When it is true an 'if' statement will perform the necessary recalculations and reset the flag so that the 'while' statement will resume.

The program works perfectly with the initial values. Phase is perfect. However when the ISR is called and comes back to the main loop, from how i understand it resumes the program in the 'while' statement from where was originally interrupted, until it finishes and re-checks the flag 'set4' to see it is now true and it should stop.
Then, even though the 'if' statement afterwards resets and re-calculates all the necessary variables the phase between these 4 output channels is lost. Tested manually i see depending on which time the ISR is called it will give different results, usually having all 4 output channels synchronised together!
This happens even though i might don't change any values (thus the 'if' routine resets the variables to exactly the same ones when you first power up the arduino!). However, if i comment out this routine and just leave the line which resets the flag 'set4' the program will continue normally like nothing never happened!

I'm pretty sure that this is somehow caused because of the micros() timer because the loop will be resumed from where the ISR was called. I've tried to do it differently by checking and disabling for interrupts using cli() and sei() but i couldn't get it to work because it will just freeze when the arguments for cli() are true. The only solution that i can think of (i've tried everything, spend the whole day searching and trying out stuff) is to force the ISR to resume from the start of the loop so that the program may initialize properly. Another solution that comes to mind is to maybe reset the micros() timer somehow..but this would mess up the ISR i believe.

To help you visualise what is going on here's a snip of my code (please don't mind the 'Millis" name in the micros variables and any missing curly brackets since it is not pure copy-paste :p):

```
    void loop()
    {
        while(!set4)
        {
        currentMillis = micros();
        currentMillis2 = micros();
        currentMillis3 = micros();
        currentMillis4 = micros();

          if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
            // save the last time you blinked the LED 
            previousMillis = currentMillis;   

            // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
            if (ledState == LOW)
            {
              interval = ONTIME;
              ledState = HIGH;
            }
            else
            {
             interval = OFFTIME; 
             ledState = LOW;
            }

            // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
            digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
            }
    .
    .
    //similar code for the other 3 output channels
    .
    .
    }
    if (set4){
    //recalculation routine - exactly the same as when declaring the variables initially  
      currentMillis = 0;
      currentMillis2 = 0;
      currentMillis3 = 0;
      currentMillis4 = 0;

      //Output states of the output channels, forced low seperately when the ISR is called (without messing with the 'ledState' variables)
      ledState = LOW;
      ledState2 = LOW;
      ledState3 = LOW;
      ledState4 = LOW;

      previousMillis = 0;
      previousMillis2 = 0;
      previousMillis3 = 0;
      previousMillis4 = 0;

     //ONTIME is the HIGH time interval of the pulse wave (i.e. dwell time), OFFTIME is the LOW time interval
     //Note the calculated phase/timing offset at each channel

      interval = ONTIME+OFFTIME;
      interval2 = interval+interval/4;
      interval3 = interval+interval/2;
      interval4 = interval+interval*3/4;

      set4=false;

    }
}
```

Any idea what is going wrong?
Kind regards,
Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  previousMillis = 0;
  previousMillis2 = 0;
  previousMillis3 = 0;
  previousMillis4 = 0;
```

All if statement will be true on the next loop.

Try with:

```
  previousMillis = micros();
  previousMillis2 = micros();
  previousMillis3 = micros();
  previousMillis4 = micros();
```

Comment: Can't believe i missed that! I swear i tried all combinations except this one, because i couldn't figure the problem logically and it was already 5 am.. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Also check out the final "product": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdODx-q1_0c Thanks again!